# How to call base class constructor in derived class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, constructor

Based on some requirements, I want to add all constructors/methods of the base class into the derived class without writing methods/constructors in the derived class.

For that I have written code as shown below but it does not work. It shows error "ConsoleApplication1.TestClass2' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".
How can I fix that?

I cannot create any method or constructor in the base class. Is there any other way apart from inheriting a class?

My code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class TestClass1
    {
        public TestClass1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor1");
        }

        public TestClass1(string str1,string str2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor2");
        }

        public TestClass1(string str1,string str2,string str3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor3");
        }

        public TestClass1(string str1,string str2,string str3,string str4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor4");
        }
    }

    public class TestClass2 : TestClass1
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass2 test = new TestClass2("test");
            TestClass2 test1 = new TestClass2("test,test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no luck. Constructors can't be inherited in C#. Your derived class will have to declare all the constructors you need. It can "chain" the constructors from the base class with `:base(...)` syntax. Your question is a duplicate of [Why can't we use a constructor with parameter in derived classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167234/) and possibly others.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the base class supposed to have these constructors? But you write _I cannot create any method or constructor in base class._ Do you want to add them to the derived class? But you write _without writing methods/constructors in derived class._ Please clarify.

Answer (score 18):

No, You'll have to explicitly add constructor to your derived classes. Base class's constructor is for base class only. You'll have to chain the constructor of your interested overload.

```
public class TestClass2 : TestClass1
{
    public TestClass2 (string str1,string str2)
    : base(str1,str2)//Call base constructor explicitly
    {

    }
}
```

Above sample shows that am particularly interested in constructor overload which takes two string parameters. In this case you are only allowed to use this overload only since `TestClass2` doesn't have any other constructors defined.

Compiler will not provide default constructor for you when you define one; So there is only way you can create instance of TestClass2 is `new TestClass2(arg1,arg2);`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public class TestClass2 : TestClass1
{
    public TestClass2()
    {
    }

    public TestClass2(string str1, string str2)
        : base(str1, str2)
    {
    }

    public TestClass2(string str1, string str2, string str3)
        : base(str1, str2, str3)
    {
    }

    public TestClass2(string str1, string str2, string str3, string str4)
        : base(str1, str2, str3, str4)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you invoke with single parameter i.e "test" and "test,test"

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class TestClass1
    {
        public TestClass1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor1");
        }


        public TestClass1(string str1, string str2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor2");
        }

        public TestClass1(string str1, string str2, string str3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor3");
        }

        public TestClass1(string str1, string str2, string str3, string str4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is base class constructor4");
        }
    }

    public class TestClass2 : TestClass1
    {
        public TestClass2(string str)
        {
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass2 test = new TestClass2("test");
            TestClass2 test1 = new TestClass2("test,test");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public TestClass2(string str):base(str) // will invoke base class constructor
 {
 }
```